# Displaying array values in contour plots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an array A which contains values that I plot using X and Y as the coordinate axes, using

```
plt.contourf(X,Y,A)
```

I'd like to know how I could obtain the values of A when I hover my cursor over a certain (X,Y) point in the plot, or any other alternative to this where I could obtain the value at any point while I am viewing the plot.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `format_coord` property of axis object:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
A = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
X = np.arange(5)
Y = np.arange(5)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
plt.contourf(X,Y,A)

nrows, ncols = A.shape
def format_coord(x, y):
    i = int(x)
    j = int(y)
    if j >= 0 and j < ncols and i >= 0 and i < nrows: 
        return "A[{0}, {1}] = {2}".format(i, j, A[i][j])
    else: return "[{0} {1}]".format(i, j)

ax.format_coord = format_coord
plt.show()
```

Example:

[image]